# Controller can't find object created by worker

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, sidekiq

Spent all day trying to fix this..

Basically the controller is calling worker to perform the creation of "Balance". The worker performs with success and the record is created but when it returns to the controller it can't find the object created. How to force it looking for the "updated database" records ?

Controller:

```
  balance = BalanceCreator.perform_async(userx.id, market.id)


  20.times do
    status = Sidekiq::Status::get balance, :exp_status
    if ["done"].include?(status)
      break
    end
    sleep(0.2)
  end

  statux = Sidekiq::Status::get balance, :exp_status
  puts statux
  # Shows correct status

  exp_id = Sidekiq::Status::get balance, :exp_id
  puts exp_id
  # Shows correct id

  user_exp = Balance.find(exp_id)
  # Error - WARN: Couldn't find Balance with 'id'=2
```

Worker

```
class BalanceCreator
  def perform(user, market)
    balance = Balance.find_or_create_by(user: user, market: market)

    puts balance.id
    # Correct id displays


    store exp_status: "done"
    exp_status = retrieve :exp_status
    store exp_id: exposure.id
    exp_id = retrieve :exp_id
  end
end
```

Comment: @matanco WARN: undefined method `perform' for ExposureCreator:Class

Comment: try put UserExposure.last.touch before the line which throw the error

Comment: @matanco it seems like its still locked or something: WARN: undefined method `touch' for nil:NilClass

Comment: Why are you trying to hack Sidekiq to execute code synchronously?

Comment: @MikePerham I need to run the code synchronously but I also need to limit the inflow to guarantee I have no concurrency/racing problems. To achieve that I am using sidekiq (hacked to be synchronously as you called) with the help of sidekiq status and sidekiq unique jobs to ensure it doesn't create more than one object simultaneously for each user - Balance.find_or_create on this example. If you know any better way I would love to hear

Comment: @MikePerham I opened a question about this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33108855/rails-4-racing-concurrency-avoid-deadlock