# Rails 4 Racing/Concurrency. Avoid Deadlock

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, multithreading, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I am currently using Sidekiq with the help of Sidekiq-Unique-Jobs and Sidekiq-Status to perform tasks on my application.

Jobs performed by workers are small and almost always executed immediately. (little or no queue at all)

I am "hacking" sidekiq to perform tasks synchronously (check [Controller can't find object created by worker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33089189/controller-cant-find-object-created-by-worker)), these jobs are small and fast to execute (less than 1 second usually). And my application needs to run the jobs synchronously and get its details (record created/updated)

With the "lame" solution I am using:

```
  20.times do
    status = Sidekiq::Status::get balance, :exp_status
    if ["done"].include?(status)
      break
    end
    sleep(0.2)
  end
```

creating a queue and ensuring via params (sidekiq-unique-jobs) that no more than 1 job is simultaneously executed by the same user I can avoid all deadlocks, however I feel that it should be a better way to perform this, rather than hacking sidekiq since it's meant to perform jobs asynchronously.

**The question is**: Is there any alternative or similar gem to sidekiq in the way that I can limit inputs BUT which is by default meant to be run synchronously? I can't just ask on controller `Balance.find_or_create_by(user: user, market: market)` because sooner or later it will give me deadlocks (records being edited /manipulated / created at the same time) but I feel that this sidekiq solution I'm using is also not ok on the long term. Am I missing something basic here?? How to ensure via middleware or something similar that duplicated params/action are not executed at the same time to avoid deadlocks?

Comment: your deadlocks are coming from sidekiq, or your _database_? Or something else? What do you mean "because sooner or later it will give me deadlocks" -- what does this look like when it happens? You get an error message from something? You get behavior you don't want? (The latter probably isn't a "deadlock", but might be a race condition). If this is about your database race conditions, there is one set of techniques; if it's really about deadlocks there is another. I think what you're asking isn't exactly what you want, but if you explain what you're actually trying to do and why it's failing..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved my problem with [Redis-Mutex](https://github.com/kenn/redis-mutex).

With this I have a native synchronous solution that can still lock the rows I am working on, and in case of row locked there are no problem because I am rescuing with a simple retry. When records become unlocked it come back and retry the work

```
  def enter
    RedisMutex.with_lock(user) do
      # hard-work
    end
  rescue RedisMutex::LockError
    retry
  end
```

Answer (score 2):

You are hacking together a poor man's distributed mutex.  There are better ways.

[FOSS](https://github.com/kenn/redis-mutex)

[Sidekiq Enterprise's official API](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Ent-Rate-Limiting#concurrent)